# Issue with class cast during post request

Tags: java, rest, groovy

```
    try {

        def contactId= "9999"
        def phoneNumber = 213213214
        def postObj = [PhoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                       ContactID  : contactId]

        def queryString = ["processAgainstExisting": true]

        def params = ["restVerb"     : "POST",
                      "postObj"      : postObj,

                      "path"         : "/contact/$contactId/PhoneNumber",
                      "query"        : queryString]

        def response = new PostRequest("Some url")
                .setParams(params)
                .execute()

        // check HttpResponse status code
        if (response.status != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException(response.statusLine)
        }

} catch (Throwable e) {
    throw e
}
```

tiedd doing the post and faced this issue.
Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Any other way to handle this issue?

Comment: Which line? Also where did you get PostRequest? Is it from a library?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the line

```
throw new RuntimeException(response.statusLine)
```

causes the exception, doesn't it?

Try

```
throw new RuntimeException(response.statusLine.toString())
```

The `statusLine` is not a `String`, but the `RuntimeException` needs a `String` message for the constructor.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html